# How to get event handlers from @ContentChildrent?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a `my-button` component, which shall be wrapped in a `my-button-row` component, like this:

```
<my-button-row>
    <my-button [label]="Some Label" (click)="func1($event)"></my-button>
    <my-button [label]="Some Other Label" (click)="func2($event)"></my-button>
</my-button-row>
```

When I read the `my-button` components in `@ContentChildren`, i cannot find out which `(click)` handler is assigned to them.

```
export class MyButtonRowComponent {
    @ContentChildren(MyButtonComponent) buttons: QueryList<MyButtonComponent>;

    ngAfterContentInit() {
        // where is the (click) setting?
        console.log(this.buttons); 
     }
}
```

The result of the `console.log(this.buttons)` is a `QueryList` with `MyButtonComponents`, which do not have an assigned `click` event or something like this. How can is find out, which event handlers have been assign to the `ContentChildren`?

Why I want to do this:

I want to wrap my content children `my-button` components one by one with some styleable `div` wrapper. So going from:

```
<my-button-row>
    <my-button [label]="Some Label" (click)="func1($event)"></my-button>
    <my-button [label]="Some Other Label" (click)="func2($event)"></my-button>
</my-button-row>
```

to this:

```
<my-button-row>
    <div class="styleme">
        <my-button [label]="Some Label" (click)="func1($event)"></my-button> 
    </div>
    <div class="styleme">
        <my-button [label]="Some Other Label" (click)="func2($event)"></my-button>
    </div>
</my-button-row>
```

All solutions I've found to create dynamic components are not suitable because they do create new components, but the `(click)="func1($event)"` is lost during the process.

Comment: Instead of me giving you the solution (which I don't know yet BTW), could you explain us what you're trying to achieve ? Because maybe you're trying something that you should not be trying, to do something that you didn't know you could do another way.

Comment: In short : **tell me what you want to do, I'll tell you the best way to do it**

Comment: Thank you, I've updated the question now.

Comment: As @trichetriche suggested, that DOM Manipulation is bad practice and @MikeSpiris suggested, that I should better correct the CSS itself, I;ve decided to apply some additional styles to `my-button-row` component itself, so that the changes i wanted to achieve via `.styleme` are now reflected in the `my-button-row` component itself.

Comment: Then upvote his solution as its closest to what you asked, and make the same comment on his answer, so that people wonderign the same thing as you can find it easily !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to surround some tags with other tags, you should not rely on your own DOM manipulation : **manipulating the DOM yourself is a bad practice in Angular**.

Instead, create a wrapper component that will surround your tags.

Something like this : **[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gzogjz?file=src%2Fapp%2Fsurrounder%2Fsurrounder.component.css)**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-surrounder',
  template: `
<div class="styleme">
    <ng-content></ng-content>
</div>
`,
  styleUrls: ['./surrounder.component.css']
})
export class SurrounderComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Comment: And as you can see on the blitz, it won't lose the function call (look at the console)

Answer (score 1):

Better approach is to set the style in `my-button` component itself. If you need multiple styles for different instances of `my-button`, maybe inject the `@Input` with the id of style you want to use on that specific instance of the component.

Comment: Thank you for giving this hint. I've decided to update the style of `<my-button-row>` to replicate the view what I've tried to achieve with surround the `<my-button>` component.